# Google Drive - "File is in owner's trash" - how to download

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I received a link to a file on Google Drive. When I try to open it, it says "**File is in owner's trash**" and there is no Download button.

How can I download it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the link looks like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/.../view` where `...` is some long ID. Replace the link by `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=...` with the same ID instead of `...` or `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=...&export=download`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Send the link to yourself on Gmail. There will be a download button at the bottom of the email.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link, the download button will appear for a split second, then disappear. In that split second, stop the browser from loading, for example by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you're too slow or too fast, reload the page and try again.

This works in Google Chrome and probably in other browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer